# Remove a list of characters from string in C#

Tags: c#, string, char

I need a method that removes a list of characters from a string. I need to support properly all characters but I'm not sure I'm managing surrogate characters properly.

Is there any better way?

```
public static string Remove(string source, char[] oldChar)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(source) || oldChar == null || oldChar.Length == 0)
        return source;

    for (int i = source.IndexOfAny(oldChar, 0); i != -1; i = source.IndexOfAny(oldChar, i))
        source = source.Remove(i, char.IsSurrogatePair(source, i) ? 2 : 1);

    return source;
}
```

Thank you

Frank

Comment: Well how do you *want* to support surrogate pairs? Because you can't represent a non-BMP character in a single `char` value anyway... perhaps your second argument should be `int[]`?

Comment: Please provide a sample input/output of what you expect.

Answer (score 3):

The following does not deal with surrogate pairs as it is not clear from the question what you want to do. If fulfils the requirement of removing a list of characters from a string

```
public static string Remove(string source, char[] oldChar)
{
    return String.Join("", source.ToCharArray().Where(a => !oldChar.Contains(a)).ToArray());
}
```

Example:

```
var s = "hello world";
var c = new[] { 'l', 'o' };
Remove(s, c); //returns: he wrd
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to remove surrogates may I suggest the following method: [`Char.ConvertFromUtf32(int utf32);`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.convertfromutf32.aspx)